# Using send() (mpsc::Sender) inside a loop

Tags: rust, tcp, channel

I'm new to Rust, sorry if this question seems out of place or very stupid.

I am trying to read data from a TCP stream `stream` and sending it to another thread by using `let (sender_buff, receiver_buff) = ::std::sync::mpsc::channel();` .

Here is my code:

```
const FRAME_SIZE:usize = 256;
let mut raw_bytes = [0 as u8; FRAME_SIZE];

let mut time_out = false;
while !time_out {
    if stream.read_exact(&mut raw_bytes).is_ok() {
        // send in the channel
        sender_buff.send(&mut raw_bytes).ok();
    }
```

However it doesn't compile:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `raw_bytes` as mutable more than once at a time
```

I have no idea on how to fix this issue, any ideas ?
Thank you.

Comment: you probably want to clone the frame you send out to the channel. otherwise (if it was C), you would send the buffer, and in the next iteration immediatelly start to overwrite the buffer, so the receiver thread can receive anything. (and since it is rust, it tells you that you did something wrong)

Comment: allocating a new buffer for each new frame should also work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is to send a `&mut` reference to the buffer which is not a very good idea.

For the sake of argument, imagine that rust allowed you to do so:

1. That buffer is stack allocated so once you exit from that function, the receiver would have a pointer to uninitialized memory, which is UB
2. That function could have overwritten that buffer while the receiver was still reading it - that too would have caused a hard to detect bug in your application.

Instead rust protected you from those two error scenarios.

What you need to do is to use a heap allocated buffer (`Vec<T>`) instead and send the buffer itself instead of a reference., which would protect you from (1). That would force you to create a new buffer on each iteration due to the move semantics, which would protect you from (2)